# KendoUI - DropDownListFor - Update and selecting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

I have a grid that is setting Editable like this:

```
.Editable(e =>
{
    e.Enabled(true);
    e.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp);             
    e.TemplateName("MyEdit");
    e.Window(w => w.Title("Gadzooks"));             
}
```

In MyEdit.cshtml I have something like this:

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Type)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Type, "MyTypeListEdit", Model.Type);
</div>
```

And finally in the editor MyTypeListEdit.cshtml:

```
@model object

@{
    string selectedValue = (string)Model;
}

@{
    SelectList selectList = new SelectList(
        new SelectListItem[] {
            new SelectListItem()
                {                   
                    Text = "Primary",
                    Value = "Primary",
                    Selected = true
                },
            new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = "Secondary",
                    Value = "Secondary"                                 
                }   
            },
            "Text",
            "Value"
        );

    @(
        Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model)
            .Name("Type")
            .BindTo(selectList)
            .DataValueField("Value")
            .DataTextField("Text")      
            .Value(selectedValue)   
    )                       
}
```

When the Model's type is Secondary it still selects Primary. (I'm assuming there is a disconnect somewhere). How can I get the editor template that is being referenced from another template which is being set in the Editable() to actually select the appropriate value. The Kendo UI documentation is lousy.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need to have to use a call to Read to get this working as well as @model object at the top. Also, don't use the name property so that it will match the property name that is being bound automatically.

```
@model object
@{
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model)
        .DataTextField("Text")
        .DataValueField("Value")        
        .DataSource(source =>
            {
                source.Read(read =>
                    {
            read.Action("GetMyList", "MyController");
                    });
            }
        ))
    }
```

Comment: Have you gotten your controller to send in a selected value for the selectlist? I cannot seem to get my dropdownlist to select a default value using the select list constructor SelectList(Ienumerable, "Text","Value",object selecteditem)

Comment: You can return an List<SelectListItem> with one of the items having Selected property set to true. You can also select the item you want on the client from javascript using the select() method.